# My map function is not working in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import SearchResult from "./SearchResult";

class Search extends Component {
    constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        data: [],
    };
    this.renderRes = this.renderRes.bind(this);
    }
    handelTextFieldChange(e) {
    fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/search-post?query=${e.target.value}`)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
            data: data,
        });
        console.log(this.state.data);
        });
    }
    renderRes() {
    return (
        <div>
        {Array(this.state.data).map((_, index, blog) => {
            return (
            <SearchResult
                content={blog[index]["body"]}
                date={String(blog[index]["date"])}
                author={blog[index]["author"]}
                title={blog[index]["title"]}
            />
            );
        })}
        </div>
    );
    }
    render() {
    return (
        <div id="search">
        <div className="search-box">
            <TextField
            id="outlined-basic"
            label="Enter any Keyword"
            variant="outlined"
            onChange={(e) => this.handelTextFieldChange(e)}
            />
        </div>
        <div className="search-results">{this.renderRes()}</div>
        </div>
    );
    }
}

export default Search;
```

My fetch data --->

```
[
{"author": "Pranav Tripathi",
 "title": "What is Diet?", "body": "In nutrition, diet is the sum of food consumed by a person or other organism.[1] The word diet often implies specific nutrition intake for health or weight-management reasons (with the two often being related). Although humans are omnivores, each culture and each person holds some food preferences or some food taboos. This may be due to personal tastes or ethical reasons. Individual dietary choices may be more or less healthy. Complete nutrition requires ingestion and absorption of vitamins, minerals, essential amino acids from protein and essential fatty acids from fat-containing food, also food energy in the form of carbohydrates, protein, and fat. Dietary habits and choices play a significant role in the quality of life, health, and longevity.", 
"date": "2021-05-23 21:15:13.603332+00:00",
 "post_id": "ABCDEF"}
]
```

There is more of it but I am sending the first one because others are mostly the same.

When I was debugging. It mostly gives undefined.
I have made the API in Django. From the backend side, it works well. But from the front end, it doesn't. I am fresher in react I am making the project to learn it, therefore, the react code is not industry standard

Comment: What is the console.log shows? And alos when do you debug the code? Looks like you need to start typing the text into `TextField` to trigger the code that pulls the data from the Back-End.

Comment: console.log shows undefined

Comment: I have tried to add the text but nothing shows up only the fetching te data and logging it

Comment: Okay are you sure that `data` is not empty?

Comment: Yeah I am sure that the data is not empty

Comment: What `console.log(data)` shows?

Comment: `Array(this.state.data).map.((_, index, blog))` is very odd. Your `data` state is already an array, so you are essentially trying to map `[ [] ]` on the first pass by wrapping it in another array constructor. I don't see why you would not use `_` instead of `blog[index]` as well.

Comment: It shows -> [
{"author": "Pranav Tripathi",
 "title": "What is Diet?", "body": "In nutrition, diet is the sum of food consumed by a person or other organism.[1] The word diet often implies specific nutrition intake for health or weight-management reasons (with the two often being related). Although humans are omnivores, each culture and each person holds some food preferences or some food taboos. This may be due to personal tastes or ethical reasons. Individual dietary choices may be more or less healthy.", 
"date": "2021-05-23 21:15:13.603332+00:00",
 "post_id": "ABCDEF"}
]

Comment: I am first converting the data to the array because after the setState the data becomes a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your data is already in array so you dont need to convert it an array again,which is the main cause of you are getting undefined,and another point is the mapping callback,it will get blog as first argument and index as second ,so the correct way to map result is as follow

```
 renderRes() {
    return (
        <div>
        {this.state.data.map((blog,index) => {
            return (
            <SearchResult
                content={blog["body"]}
                date={String(blog["date"])}
                author={blog["author"]}
                title={blog["title"]}
            />
            );
        })}
        </div>
    );
    }
```

Comment: After implementing the code. when start typing any text in the text field It is giving TypeError: this.state.data.map is not a function

Comment: Now When I checked the type of this.state.data it is giving me string

Comment: what is the string ? if its json string then you need to parse it to object

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I had just forgotten to parse the data

Answer (score 0):

if you data is an array why dont you just

```
 return (
                  <SearchResult
                    content={blog.body}
                    date={blog.date}
                    author={blog.author}
                    title={blog.title}
                />
 )
})
```

or you can just simple pass {...blog} to your component

Comment: I have just shown a part of the data. The actual data is pretty big. So, I have just shown the first obj of the array